# Is there a way to set a HERE UI Button to disabled?

Tags: here-api

I am using a custom-created button on my HERE Map using the JS 3.0 library.

I followed a HERE support engineer's suggestion provided here: [HERE Map UI JS - How to add custom buttons to the Map UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58864755/here-map-ui-js-how-to-add-custom-buttons-to-the-map-ui)

So far, I have been able to get it to work just fine, but I just found out that I need to be able to enable or disable the button depending on various business rules. But it looks like there is no "setDisabled" functionality for HERE Controls or Buttons?

https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.ui.Control.html
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.ui.base.Button.html#.State (I saw that there was the option to initialize a button to be disabled, but not to change an existing one. Seems inefficient to create a new button every time I need to enable or disable it.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: This can also be achieved by setVisibility of element or removeClass, where the button can be set to disabled. please refer documentation for more details : developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.ui.base.Button.html#.State

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport Could you clarify how that could help? Doesn't setVisibility just show or hide the button? Or what is the class we would need to remove from the button to make it disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Dont use the `var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, maptypes, 'en-US');` line in order to disable buttons or find your self in an "if" statment to access this when a certain button is pressed or statement is passe

Answer (score 0):

There is a `setDisabled()` method inherited from the parent class `H.ui.base.Element` which you can use:

```js
// assume custom UI control exists
customControl.setDisabled(true) // <- disables the control
customControl.setDisabled(false) // <- enables the control
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zfr8gm09/) is jsfiddle working example of custom UI control which disables itself after click.

See [H.ui.Control#setDisabled()](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.ui.Control.html#setDisabled) for more details.

Comment: Do you know if any CSS should be being tied to a disabled element? I tried disabling my custom control but it seems like nothing is reflecting the change.

Comment: I updated my answer with link to working example on jsfiddle. As you can see, I added "H_icon" class to the svg element in order to visually see differences between enabled and disabled UI control.